# Python: Need advice on improving code for a simple blackjack game

Tags: python

Im new to python and for my first project on my own I'm trying to do a blackjack game

```
while True:

print('Hello, and welcome, to Blackjack!!')


thedeck = Deck()
thedeck.shuffle()

c = input('Please enter your name: ')
d = int(input('Please enter the amount of money you would like to put on the line'))
c = Human(d)
c.cards.append(thedeck.deal())
dealer = Dealer()
dealer.cards.append(thedeck.deal())

print('The dealers cards are {}'.format(dealer.cards[0]))
print('Your cards are {} and {}'.format(c.cards[0],c.cards[1]))      



while playing:
    hit_or_stand(c,thedeck)

    print('The dealers cards are {}'.format(dealer.cards[0])
    print('Your cards are: {}' .format(c.cards))     
    if playerbusts(c) == True:
        print('You have lost the game')
        int(c.totalmoney) = int(c.totalmoney) - 100
        print('You lost 100 ')
        break
    else:
        while sum(values[cards.split(" ")][0] for card in dealer.cards) < 17:
            dealer.card2()
        if dealerbusts(dealer) == True:
            print('You have won the game')
            int(c.totalmoney) = int(c.totalmoney) + 100
            print('You gained 100')
        elif dealerwins(dealer) == True:
            print('You have lost the game')
            int(c.totalmoney) = int(c.totalmoney) - 100
            print('You lost 100 ')
        elif playerwins(player) == True:
            print('You have won the game')
            int(c.totalmoney) = int(c.totalmoney) + 100
            print('You gained 100 ')
            e = input('would you like to play again??: ')
  if dealerbusts(dealer) == True or dealerwins(dealer) == True or playerbusts(c) == True or playerwins(c) == True:
      e = input('would you like to play again??: ')
      if e.lower == 'yes':
        playing = True
      if e.lower == 'no':
        playing = False    

  break
```

Deck, Human, Dealer are all predefined classes. Cards is an empty list defined under Human and Dealer. Dealerbusts, Playerbusts etc are all predefined functions for an endgame scenario

Right now, upon running this, I get:

```
print('Your cards are: {}' .format(c.cards))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know how to fix this and I'm fairly certain this isn't the only thing that's wrong here, so please do tell me the flaws.

Answer (score 2):

The error appears because there's a missing ")" in the line before:

```py
print('The dealers cards are {}'.format(dealer.cards[0]) # <- here
```

Also there are some indent errors in the while True loop. (I suppose that this may also be a copy-paste error from copying your code to GitHub.)

Comment: @MNISharuya PS: Have you defined the "playing" variable before?